# Merge sum rows with multiindex with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to merge and sum rows that appear in both dataframes with multiindex, while adding the ones that are unique to each dataframe.

`df1`

```
       Amount1 Amount2 Amount3
A R10  1        1          20
  R3   0        0          20
  X2   1        0          20
B XS1  1        5          10 
  LM2  1        1          10
C RR1  2        1          30
```

`df2`

```
       Amount1 Amount2 Amount3
A R10  1        1          20
  X2   1        0          20
B XS1  1        5          10 
  XF2  1        1          10
C RR1  2        1          30
```

Final result:

```
       Amount1 Amount2 Amount3
A R10  2        2          40
  R3   0        0          20
  X2   2        0          40
B XS1  2        10         20 
  LM2  1        1          10
  XF2  1        1          10
C RR1  4        2          60
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
       Amount1  Amount2  Amount3
A R10      2.0      2.0     40.0
  R3       0.0      0.0     20.0
  X2       2.0      0.0     40.0
B LM2      1.0      1.0     10.0
  XF2      1.0      1.0     10.0
  XS1      2.0     10.0     20.0
C RR1      4.0      2.0     60.0
```